# How do I manage stateful data for database objects in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, database, caching

In a project I have to process a lot of order (as in purchase) data. Together
with the order data, I have to generate state information that somehow has to
be cached. I'm unsure about good ways of managing such data.

## Models

```
class Order:
  buyer_name = TextField()

class OrderItem:
  order = ForeignKey(Order)
  quantity = IntegerField()
  name = TextField()
```

## Requirements

- The buyer name is being checked for validity by looking at the characters
  and querying an external API.
- It's also checked if there are multiple orders from the same buyer (→
  duplicates).
- The user must be able to filter orders according to their check results.
- Last, but not least, every order has a condition that's directly dependent
  on check results:

  - Buyer name is valid, no duplicate order: Order condition is OK.
  - Buyer name is valid, duplicate order: Order condition is Warning.
  - Buyer name is invalid: Order condition is Error.

## Issue

**My question: What's a good way of storing information such as conditions or
check results?**

I might also have to query for the total quantity count per order without
joining and aggregating the item quantities all the time (performance).

Comment: Why don't you just store those "check results" and state in the Order ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It's what I do, but it doesn't feel right. I also need data like order totals. Storing both the total itself & the order items that are used to calculate the total, feels weird.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't feel right? **State** is property of **Order**. It doesn't mean that it has to be stored in the database.

Comment: @cezar Because I will have to keep Order.total synchronized to the underlying data, which I feel is somehow an indicator of a design flaw. I have no idea how others are doing it, that's why I'm asking. ;-)
If it's not in the database, it's hard/impossible to query it, I guess that's an issue.

Comment: If the **Order** has some **State**, which is calculated using other available data, you can make it a so called virtual property. I'll post an answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, there is a property of your model which is changing all the time and can be calculated using the data stored in the database. Simple example would be a class **Person**. The class **Person** has properties like name, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, etc. Beyond that age is also a property of **Person**. But we don't save that property in the database as it is dynamically changing depending on other factors (date_of_birth and now). It could look like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @cached_property
    def age(self):
        # get today's date (for example using timezone.now())
        # and calculate the age today - date_of_birth
        # return the age in years as integer
        return age
```

Now you can use that property everywhere, it is cached and makes no further database queries.

And than in your template you could do this:

```
{% extend "base.html" %}
<p>{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.</p>
```

I hope this gives you an idea and you can work it out for your particular case. You can also use the decorator `@property`, however Django's `@cached_property` gives you more possibilities, like caching.
You can import it like this:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
```

Comment: That's nice, however one requirement is that I'm able to query the database for the cached data — so it indeed has to exist at the DB level somehow. But @cached_property is super interesting for other parts in my project.